# How to get the authorization code from query params // Amazon Cognito authorization endpoint

Tags: jsp, servlets, oauth-2.0, oauth, amazon-cognito

I am trying to hit cognito authorization URL on a jsp load. When the JSP gets called, I call a java method in my jsp. Following is the code snippet:

```
public static void getData(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_FOUND);
    response.setHeader("Location",
            "https://test.us-west-2.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/authorize?redirect_uri=https://test.com&client_id=123456789&response_type=code");
}
```

The users successfully gets redirected when they hit the jsp. The authorization code `code` is appended to the url (I can see in the tomcat logs).

I need the authorization code in my method. I have tried getting it from request `request.getParameter("code");`, but that didn't work.

How do I get the code? Its appended to the url as a query param.

> user [14/Jul/2021:15:35:43 -0400] "GET
> /app?code=fdsfs-fsd-4324-4324-fdsfsdfjh5u34 HTTP/1.1" 302 - 6553

Answer (score 0):

Generally you will use a library that parses the response URL into an object. This depends on your technology which you have not specified.

As an example see [this code snippet](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample1/blob/master/spa/src/plumbing/oauth/authenticator.ts#L127) which runs in a browser and gets the code into `urlData.query.code` - it uses the [url-parse library](https://github.com/unshiftio/url-parse).

Comment: I am writing code in Java. When I print `request.getParameterMap()`, I don't see the code at all in my logs.

Comment: I think you can just do request.getParameter("code")

Comment: I tried request.getParameter("code"), but getting null. I checked the tomcat logs and do see that the code is being appended the end. 

`user [14/Jul/2021:15:35:43 -0400] "GET /app?code=fdsfs-fsd-4324-4324-fdsfsdfjh5u34 HTTP/1.1" 302 - 6553`

Comment: Just updated my question with some more information.